# Retrieve the object a method belongs to

Tags: python

```
def decorator(func):
    pass

class DummyClass:
    @decorator
    def func(self):
        pass

dummy = DummyClass()
```

How can I retrieve the DummyClass object in the decorator or how can I send the object as an argument to the decorator itself?

Comment: Could you tell us more on what your are trying to achieve? What problem are you facing? What is the expected outout?

Comment: I am using the discordpy sdk and it has a functional approach to making bots and uses decorators to add commands but just out of curiosity i tried a class based approach and want to add command via a decorator but for that i need to access the object in the decorator. I've found another approach to the problem; but i was wondering if this is possible in python so i posted this question

Answer (score 1):

Your function `decorator` is not actually a decorator.  A decorator in Python is, in simple cases, a function that returns another function.  Your "decorator" doesn't do this.

The decorator syntax causes the old function (the function being decorated) to be replaced by the new one (the one returned by the decorator).

What you are trying to do, I think, is to replace a member function with another member function.  All member functions take at least one argument, conventionally named "self."  It refers to the object itself.  Therefore, your returned function should take one argument.  It doesn't matter if you name it "self" or not.  If you use that decorator on a member function, Python will automatically supply a first argument which will be equivalent of "self."

Here is an example showing how this works:

```
def decorator(f):
    def f1(arg0):
        print("f1")
        f(arg0)
        print(arg0.value)
        print(arg0.__class__)
    return f1

class DummyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 42
        
    @decorator
    def func(self):
        print("func")
        
    @decorator
    def func2(self):
        print("func2")

dummy = DummyClass()
dummy.func()
dummy.func2()
```

This prints:

```
f1
func
42
<class '__main__.DummyClass'>
f1
func2
42
<class '__main__.DummyClass'>
```

As you can see, you access the member objects of DummyClass with the standard dot syntax.  The first argument to the decorated function is an instance of class "DummyClass".  The example also shows how you can decorate more than one function with the same decorator.

You could also use the same decorator in another class, provide the class defines a member variable named "value."  If it doesn't, the expression `arg0.value` will raise an AttributeError.

Comment: So you can access the class with `func.__class__`, to be short. This is a complete and correct answer that also explains what a decorator is, so it deserves a +1

Comment: That was an error on my part. I forgot to return the function. Although this works but we still have to run the method to perform the actions on the method by the decorator. What I was looking for was to be able to access the object of the method without having to call the method.

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO `func.__class__` does not return the object the method belongs to

Comment: In general, a method doesn't belong to an object, it belongs to a class.  That's why the first argument to a member function is "self," i.e., the specific object on whose state the method will act.  So how do you plan to access the method?  If you write a line of code like dummy.func(), then `dummy` can perhaps be called "the object the method belongs to."  The same object can also be accessed as `dummy.func.__self__` but I don't know why you would do that.

Comment: ah, I get it now. I always associated methods with objects and hence thought there must be a way to retrieve the object from the method.

Comment: Have a look to functool.wraps: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps